# How can I work around Eclipse ADB unable to establish loopback connection?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, loopback

I'm using a school computer to do some Android programming. It worked for awhile, until suddenly I got this error message:

```
[2012-05-01 07:55:19 - ddms]Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection
[2012-05-01 07:56:35 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2012-05-01 07:56:36 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
```

I've tried resetting the ADB. I've tried killing and restarting the ADB from a command window. I ran the command:

```
E:\Java\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>netsh interface teredo set state disa
bled
Ok.
```

I don't have access to the control panel or the C drive. It could be the school's firewall that is preventing me from establishing the connection. Does anyone know of a work around so I can get back to programming?

Comment: Talk to the IT dept at the school and have them help you out??

Answer (score 2):

problem in IPv6 enabled:
change last string in ddms.bat

```
call %java_exe% %java_debug% -Dcom.android.ddms.bindir=%prog_dir% -classpath "%jarpath%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.ddms.Main %*
```

after `%java_debug%` add following

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

for eclipse change `eclipse.ini`:

```
 openFile
-vmargs
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it stop working while you were using Eclipse, or did you return to the machine and find that it no longer worked?

Typically when this happens for me it is sufficient to unplug the device (or shutdown the emulator completely), kill adb (`adb kill-server`), close Eclipse, then restart adb (`adb start-server`) and then plug the device back in (or restart the emulator).

Answer (score 0):

Try, from your device, disabling usb debugging then re-enabling the feature. On some of my devices it seems the ADB failure is on the device and not on the client machine running Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are probably working on Windows (looking at the path) but resetting my USB stack solved this for me on Ubuntu.  The other solutions discussed had limited success.

Restart udev by entering `sudo service udev restart` in the terminal.